# Restore AND share trained variables: Key not found

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

I'm borrowing the example from the [sharing variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope) tutorial:

```
def my_image_filter(input_images):
    with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
        # Variables created here will be named "conv1/weights", "conv1/biases".
        relu1 = conv_relu(input_images, [5, 5, 32, 32], [32])
    with tf.variable_scope("conv2"):
        # Variables created here will be named "conv2/weights", "conv2/biases".
        return conv_relu(relu1, [5, 5, 32, 32], [32])
```

Say I trained these variables and save all four variables: `weights` and `biases` from `conv1` and `conv2` layers by passing `var_list` to `tf.train.Saver`.

Now I want to restore and use them twice:

```
with tf.variable_scope("image_filters") as scope:
    result1 = my_image_filter(image1)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    result2 = my_image_filter(image2)
```

But the variables' names now have `image_filters` as prefix, i.e `image_filters/conv1/weights`, so the saver can't restore them: `Key image_filters/conv1/weights not found in checkpoint`

How do I restore the all the trained variables and reuse them multiple times?

Comment: Can you just execute the graph multiple times with different feed images?
 If not, there is the [var_list argument to the Saver's constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__), which can be a dictionary mapping checkpoint variable names to Variables in the graph they should be restored in. You can also do [more complicated restoration into modified graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398708/6824418)...

Comment: @AllenLavoie I did use the `var_list` argument of Saver to save, but after that I can't seem to get the same `var_list` to restore with the different variable scope. Or maybe I'm not sure what you mean. Can you demonstrate?

Comment: I just mean that you could use a dictionary mapping checkpoint names (no "image_filters/") to Variable objects (named with "image_filters/" as a prefix) if it's not possible to use the same variable_scope in the original model. If it's painful to dig up the Variable objects, have a look at my second link for an example of iterating over collections of variables in a checkpoint.

Comment: @AllenLavoie If you provide that as an answer, I'd accept it.